# JavaScript - switching classes of element does not work the first time

Tags: javascript, css

I have this simple function that is invoked whenever I click on a button:

```
$scope.Set_Above_Feasibility_Max = function (p_Index , p_Parameter_Name) {
    
    document.getElementById("Param_Input_" + p_Index).classList.remove("my-Less-than-min") ;
    document.getElementById("Param_Input_" + p_Index).classList.add("my-More-than-max") ;
    :
    :
}
```

The result *should* be that the selected element would change its appearance.

Strangely, I need to click ***TWICE*** on the button for the change to take place.

There is a second button that switches appearance in the opposite way, and the same strange situation applies (the code is identical except for the classes being removed/added).

No errors are shown at all. Why might this be the case, and how to resolve it?

Comment: put a debugger in the start of function and try to debug in chrome browser's console, check whether the class you are trying to remove exists or not?

Comment: Thank you @AnkushJain for your suggestion. This is not the source of the issue because: (1) If there is an issue when attempting to remove a class, why does it work when I click on the button for the second time?  (2), I wrapped the class removal with the `try{...} catch(e) {...}` and still it does not work, and finally (3), there are no errors in the console of the debugger.

Comment: The problem is most likely with how you're connecting the function to the button click. Since you haven't shown that, we can't help you.